# Why did Harry use Expelliarmus in book 4?

Tags: harry-potter

When callenged to a duel by Voldemort in the graveyard in book 4, Harry swears to "go down fighting". And yet he uses his least offensive battle spell, not even trying to cause actual harm.

I don't mean he should've instantly resorted to Avada Kedavra, but even something like Stupefy would've gotten Voldemort out of the fight if it hit. Any reason for him to remain a pacifist even after choosing to fight? (Harry did learn the stunning spell in preparation for the Third Task, if I remember correctly.)

Comment: Given that you need a wand for magic ('wandless' magic is never seen done by someone who doesn't posses a wand), and possibly even apparation, an enemy who is disarmed is effectively dead from the standpoint of combat effectiveness.  A stunned enemy is as well, but requires only a single *Innervate* for an ally to restore.  Disarmed = defeated.

Comment: So your question is, why isn’t the protagonist a murderer.

Answer (score 10):

I'd like to go a bit deeper into Richard's comment on his answer about being under pressure and on how Rowling constructed the scene.

In that particular scene, there's this very telling paragraph about what's going on in Harry's mind.

> ...Harry remembered,...the dueling club at Hogwarts he had attended briefly two years ago.... All he had learned there was the Disarming Spell, "*Expelliarmus*".
>
> <sub><sup>GoF, Chapter 34, p660. Scholastic Edition.</sup></sub>

So from the onset, *Expelliarmus* filled Harry's mind. He did not intend to do it. At the time, he was not taking moral high ground that he's no Voldemort so he won't kill. It was *instinct* that made Harry use *Expelliarmus*.

Personally, I think this is where *Expelliarmus* became his signature spell. I could go into all my theories about what's going on in Harry's mind between the lines but that's out of place here so I'll just leave you with a personal real-life observation that mirrors this reflex from Harry.

I trained in Taekwondo and I noticed that (applies even in my case), the first time white-belts spar, they don't use the good techniques they are supposed to know but the most basic one. It does not give the most points nor is it KO-quality. Most are not aiming to win. Nervous as they are, they just want to retaliate enough to survive the round.

Very same conditions with Harry, if not more intense. Note that he has been using *Expelliarmus* since his second year. He has used it in his third year against grown-up wizards (Snape and Black). Compare that to Stunning which he only learned not too long ago for the third task. It's not far-fetched that faced with intense pressure from another more-powerful wizard, he'd stick to what experience has proven effective.

**TL;DR** Harry was not trying to save the day and kill Voldemort. He was acting out of survival instinct so he fell back on *Expelliarmus*.

Comment: I agree with all of this. When given time to think, he improvised and uses advanced magic. When **openly confronted** with an enemy, he blindly goes to his go-to spell.

Comment: great answer! In short, Expelliarmus was his *Kata*. A move he was trained to do automatically in a dueling situation, without consciousness kicking in.

Answer (score 1):

In short, it's because Harry doesn't use magic offensively (or when he does, he does so with extreme reluctance). Note that in all seven books, he never directly kills **anyone**.

Also, it's arguably his "signature spell". He feels very comfortable with it and knows precisely how to use it to best effect:

> *‘So you think I should have killed Stan Shunpike?’ said Harry angrily.*
>
> *‘Of course not,’ said Lupin, ‘but the Death Eaters – frankly, most
>   people! – would have expected you to attack back! Expelliarmus is a
>   useful spell, Harry, but the Death Eaters seem to think it is your
>   signature move, and I urge you not to let it become so!’ Lupin was
>   making Harry feel idiotic, and yet there was still a grain of defiance
>   inside him. **‘I won’t blast people out of my way just because they’re
>   there,’ said Harry. ‘That’s Voldemort’s job.’***
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sup></sub>

Comment: Stupefy was a spell Harry deliberately learned for the Tournament and used it in the Third task against Krum. He also had used Stupefy at least as many times "on-screen" as Expelliarmus at that point. I ask again: why not at least stun a man that's trying to take your life?

Comment: @user38452 - Under pressure, we go to the things we know best.

Comment: @user38452 You also have to consider that in the Tournament you could use anything you'd like. If you disarm Krum, he can probabbly run to you and punch you in the face. I don't see the skeletic Voldemort doing that

Comment: I would have to bring up one point ... Malloy would have died in *The Half Blood Prince* when he and Harry fought in the bathroom, except Snape saves his life. You cannot tell me Harry wasn't trying to do some serious damage to Draco there. He was actually trying to kill him and would have had Severus not intervened.

Comment: @Paulster2 In fairness, part of the point of *HPB* is Harry's teenage hormones finally catching up to him, and his making some less-than-wise decisions as a result. That book has some of the least-consistent characteriziation in the series (at least in my opinion), so why should this be any different?

Comment: @Paulster2 Harry didn't know what the spell did when he used it on Malfoy. I think it's a reasonable assumption that if he'd known what it did he would never have used it on Malfoy in that situation.

Comment: @CreationEdge Harry knows the spell is "for enemies" though. And he knows (based on the success of the tips in his copy of Advanced Potion-Making) that anything the Half Blood Prince puts together is likely to be effective in its purpose... what did he expect the spell to do to an ememy? It can't have been anything nice!

Comment: @TheGiantofLannister - It's perhaps worth noting that *rictu*sempra is the tickling charm. Similar name, vastly different effects.

Comment: @Richard I'm not entirely sure how that is relevant. For instance in the English language the words "appointed" and "disappointed" differ by just 3 letters but have completely different meanings and would be used in different contexts. Unless you are telling me that the catalogue of spells in HP has a sort of logic behind it that usually groups spells by common syllables/suffixes/prefixes (over and beyond the superficial references to Latin of course). And that Harry could reasonably have believed it was a harmless spell as a result.

Comment: Suffice to say I do not think that is the case. I would expect any defence of Harry's actions to lay on the grounds of his morals (that Harry wanted to hurt/harm/humiliate Draco but not to the extent of putting Draco in mortal danger). To be honest, I think that is what Harry was trying to achieve. So I was really just playing Devil's advocate by pointing out that Harry erred in judgement at the very least.

Comment: @TheGiantofLannister - A reasonable point, but wandering off the topic for this question. I'm happy to move these comments to chat if you want to continue the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment when Harry did cast the spell, he didn't think he has any chance to survive:

> And as he heard Voldemort draw nearer still, he knew one thing only, and it was beyond fear or reason: He was not going to die crouching here like a child playing hide-and-seek; he was not going to die kneeling at Voldemort s feet... he was going to die upright like his father, and he was going to die trying to defend himself, even if no defense was possible

Don't forget also that he was surrounded by Death Eathers. Even if he somehow manages to incapacitate Voldemort it is very likely that they will kill him just for revenge.

So it didn't matter which spell Harry will use. Expeliarmus was the first (offensive) spell that he learned so maybe he just decided to use it as a "sign of resistance" rather than as a path to victory.